# Binary Matrix covered with squares to cover all $'s in min cost

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I came across a question where we are given a binary matrix of size NxN. It consists of a '-' and a '$' sign. We can perform the following operation:

- we can take a square of size M X M (1 <= M <= N) and convert all $'s to -'s in this submatrix this operation costs M coins

For example:

```
$$---
-$$--
$-$--
-----
----$
```

**The output of the above code is 4.**

**Explanation**: 6 '$' signs on the top left can be covered under a square submatrix of 3x3 with cost 3. The '$' on the right bottom can be considered a square submatrix of 1x1 with size 1. Thus, total cost= 3+1=4

**The aim is to minimize the cost.**

What is the approach? I was thinking to use DFS for this problem but later found out it's not going to work. I tried working it out similar to the number of islands problem but it didn't.

It will be great if someone can provide the code in Python for better understanding.